# Excel VBA - copy&paste a whole row from a closed workbook to my active workbook if certain criteria are met

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have a workbook with a macro that imports data regarding information about active notifications for outstanding work on aircraft from a text file that is automatically saved to a location every 2hrs. Each row is for a different notification and in each column is data such as notification number, aircraft Registration, description of work, required completion time etc.

A separate macro then re-organises the data into the correct format. 
The user can then write remarks about the progress of the work next to the notification in another column.

A final macro then archives this by saving a copy of this file to a folder with a specific name dependent on the date/time called "WORK PLAN hhmm_ddmmyyyy".

Because not all of these notifications are completed in the 2hrs between text file dumps the newly imported data will contain the active notifications from the previous text file that have not been fully completed as well as a bunch of new notifications. The problem is that when the new text file is imported by the user into the active workbook all of the remarks are lost. To save copying and pasting manually the remarks for each notification that is still active from the archived file I would like a macro to be able to do this.

I need a macro that can recognise any notification numbers in column I that are present in both the most recently archived workbook and my active workbook, and then copies that row from the archived workbook and pastes it over the row with the same notification number in the active workbook.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. This is not a free code-writing service, so please post your code if you want help and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that Opens a readyonly version of a file.

Determines the rows and columns and adds the data from the readonly file to the first empty row on the sheet.

```
Sub OpenWB()'You will need to open the workbook as readonly. that way the original one is not busy when the other macro tries to update it.

Dim Your_2_hr_WB As Workbook

Workbooks.Open Filename:="FilePath & name", ReadOnly:=True

Dim Number_of_Rows As Long
Dim Number_of_Columns As Long
Dim This_Num_Rows As Long
Dim This_Num_Cols As Long


For Each Your_2_hr_WB In Workbooks
    If Your_2_hr_WB.Name = "What ever name it is " Then
    Exit For
End If
Next
Number_of_Rows = Your_2_hr_WB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Number_of_Columns = Your_2_hr_WB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column
This_Num_Rows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(This_Num_Rows + 1, 1).Resize(Number_of_Rows, Number_of_Columns).Value = Your_2_hr_WB.Cells(1, 1).Resize(Number_of_Rows, Number_of_Columns).Value

'You can replace  Your_2_hr_WB.Cells(1, 1) with  Your_2_hr_WB.Cells(2, 1) if you have a header row


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, its much appreciated. I managed to find a way of doing it in the end using the VLOOKUP function to solve my problem.